# Using NGINX + PHP-FPM + MySQL and persistent connection

Tags: mysql, nginx, php-fpm

Can I use persistent connection when using combination of `NGINX + PHP-FPM`?

Answer (score 2):

There would be nothing holding you back by doing so (though I have never done it before), but I would highly advise not to use persistent connections in MySQL. It would just give your server way more overhead than what it needs.

Take a look at the below Stack Overflow link for some more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252612/mysql-persistent-connections

If you want more performance out of your server, take a look into HTTP caching like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/). Varnish will have a much heavier impact on your performance than enabling persistent connections.